# Exception thrown by application class 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.:119'

Tags: java, soap, ibm-cloud

I am trying to Deploy a Java application over Bluemix. When I deploy it on my local `Liberty Server(Liberty 16.0.0.2)`, it works fine and I am able to hit the URL from a `SOAP` client.

But when I try it on Bluemix, it gives me this error:

> Exception thrown by application class
>   'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.:119'
>   java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY012 stack shape inconsistent;
>   class=com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl,
>   method=createDocumentFragment()Lorg/w3c/dom/DocumentFragment;, pc=5;
>   Type Mismatch, argument 0 in signature
>   com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentFragment.:(Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/CoreDocumentImpl;)V
>   does not match Exception Details: Location:
>   com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl.createDocumentFragment()Lorg/w3c/dom/DocumentFragment;
>   @5: JBinvokespecial Reason: Type
>   'com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl' (current frame,
>   stack[2]) is not assignable to
>   'com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/CoreDocumentImpl' Current
>   Frame: bci: @5 flags: { } locals: {
>   'com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl' } stack: {
>   'uninitialized', 'uninitialized',
>   'com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl' } at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.(SOAPPartImpl.java:119)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:89)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.getSOAPPart(Message1_1Impl.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJInInterceptor.java:101)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContextImpl.getMessage(SOAPMessageContextImpl.java:78)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.getOpQName(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:294)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.AbstractJAXWSHandlerInterceptor.setupBindingOperationInfo(AbstractJAXWSHandlerInterceptor.java:111)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.createProtocolMessageContext(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:144)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:119)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:69)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:89)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:99)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:368)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:183)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:163)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.doGet(AbstractCXFServlet.java:145)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
>   at [internal classes]

I already tried deploying packaged liberty server and Server directory options. But it doesn't work. 
I also tried, with `ibm-web-ext.xml` approach, where we change  `fileServingEnabled="false"`. But it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand upon Dinesh's answer, in order to instruct the Bluemix JVM to use your bundled libraries (instead of CFX), add the following to `jvm.options` in the server root (create if necessary):

```
-Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl
-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPFactory1_1Impl
-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnectionFactory
-Djavax.xml.soap.MetaFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to conflict of libraries between SOAP CFX Services (this might be bundled by the app) and the libraries in JRE.

To overcome this, pass the following as VM arguments to instruct your JVM to use appropriate libraries bundled with JRE (instead of CFX).

> javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory =
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl
>   javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory =
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPFactory1_1Impl
>   javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory =
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnectionFactory
>   javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory =
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl

Comment: Works in jvm.options file providing you include -D in front of each line.
e.g. -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand what Justin said, here is the command to run if you're using Liberty Server and pushing to it through CLI

```
cf set-env WebServicesSOAP IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS "-Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl -Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPFactory1_1Impl -Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnectionFactory -Djavax.xml.soap.MetaFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl"
```

PS: for more information about cf command, go [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/cfcommands/index.html#cf)