# Getting runtime JVMVRFY012 answer in WAS 8.5

Tags: spring, web-services, websphere, soapui, incompatibility

I deployed an EAR in Websphere 8.5 with JDK 1.7 (IBM). My application is a spring based app that expose only web services; it have the following features:

- Classloader is set to PARENT_LAST
- Has shared libraries, one of them has Spring Framework (4.3.2) and Apache CXF (3.1.9) jars.
- I invoke it through SOAPUI(5.2.1).
- The application starts without problems.

When I invoke it I receive the following error message:

```
00000146 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper
service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet CXFServlet: 
java.lang.VerifyError: **JVMVRFY012** tamaño de pila incoherente; 
clase=com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl, 
método=createDocumentFragment()Lorg/w3c/dom/DocumentFragment;, pc=5
```

I read a related answer to that error and aplied [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302503/exception-thrown-by-application-class-com-sun-xml-messaging-saaj-soap-soapparti), but got the following error:

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: **Unable to create message factory for SOAP: 
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl 
incompatible with javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory**
```

I am going to debug Apache CXF libraries to try figure it out the problem. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014932506

Comment: If you are bundling your own WS engine then you have to disable provided by WAS check [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5)

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve my problem. It was a conflicting library problem between WAS and app libs. I deleted the following libraries from my WEB-INF/lib folder:

- javax.xml.soap-api
- saaj-impl

Thanks!